# console.log output on live network

Tags: solidity, hardhat, contract-debugging, smart-contract

how to read the output of console.log() (it doesn't appear on my hardhat node console ) when i m running a smart contract on goerli (alchemy) via a js script (hardhat) ?

```
import "hardhat/console.sol";
contract BookStore {
function hello() external {
console.log("hello");}  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not see the console.log on testnet/mainnet. If your want the logs for testing, you could use events. The events are visible on chain. Or you could use a forked network locally and see the console.logs there.
Hope it help

Answer (score 2):

Use `Events` for that.

```
contract BookStore {

event Hello(string indexed bello);

function hello() external {
emit Hello("bello");
}  

}
```

For more info about the events read this: https://github.com/CJ42/All-About-Solidity/blob/master/articles/Events.md